What pH will a pH 13 sodium hydroxide solution drop to exposed to air, and how fast?
Let’s say I dropped a bottle of lye heavy, liquid soap with a pH of 13.
If this soap lies around exposed to air, what pH will it drop to once the sodium hydroxide has turned into sodium carbonate? And how fast will this happen - days, months… ?

Depending on the rate of evaporation, there might be a layer of solid soap formed on top that greatly delays the absorption of CO2 for months or more. Too many variables to give a meaningful answer.

Nothing beats the old school washing or soaked fabric cleaning, perhaps with addition of vinegar for neutralisation of residues.
